# Exclamatory 'how'

Tags: grammar, exclamatives

We use **'how'** in exclamatory sentences, generally in this structure:
How + adjective/adverb (subject + verb), as in :

> How gorgeous she is!

What about this sentence?

> How you've grown!
>   How I wish I had one of those cars!

Is it grammatically correct?

And if yes, isn't it more grammatical to say:

> How **much** you've grown!
>   How **much** I wish I had one of those cars!

Comment: _How you've grown!_ and _How much you've grown!_ are equally grammatical, and all of your uses of the exclamation are proper. By the way, a verb is not required; for instance, you could say of the subject in your first example: _How gorgeous!_

Answer (score 1):

> How you've grown.
>   How much you grown.

both your sentences are correct but can have slightly different meaning, the first might be used about *character* or *physical (sexual) maturity*, where as the second is often used for *height* or *size*.

And often that your sentences are preceeded by

> ***Oh my look*** how you've grown.
>   ***Oh my look*** how much you've grown.